# Using flexbox to align 3 items in a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to align three div's in one row at a 800px break point.

I have two break points in my code and everything works until it hits 800px. At 800px, 'Reviewer 3' ends up on it's own line below 'Reviewer 1 & 2'.

```css
  .cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.border {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.center {
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  h3 {
    color: blue;
  }
  .cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .border {
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .center {
    display: relative;
    left: 0;
  }
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .card-1,
  .card-2 {
    margin: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .card-3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    h3 {
      color: red;
    }
    .cards {
      display: flex-box;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .card-1,
    .card-2,
    .card-3 {
      margin: 30px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
      width: 30%;
      height: 20%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card-1">
      <h3>Reviewer 1</h3>
      <img class="center" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="placeholder">
      <p class="border">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam."</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card-2">
      <h3>Reviewer 2</h3>
      <img class="center " src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="placeholder">
      <p class="border">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam."</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-3">
    <h3>Reviewer 3</h3>
    <img class="center" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="placeholder">
    <p class="border" id="b3">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam."</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is an HTML problem. The third box is outside the `.wrapper` element.

Also, use `flex-basis` or `min-width` instead of `width`. Finally, are you sure you want to use `left: 30%`?

**Update**:

- Move `@media (min-width: 600px)` below `@media (min-width: 800px)` so the `600` one will override when the screen hits the breakpoint
- Add some `calc()` statements to account for borders + margin
- Add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.wrapper` (not `.cards`) because `.wrapper` is the parent of `.card-1`, `.card-2`, and `.card-3` (not `.cards`).

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.border {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  /* This works for wrapper's children, namely card-1, card-2, card-3 */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card-1,
.card-2,
.card-3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  h3 {
    color: blue;
  }

  .card-1,
  .card-2 {
    margin: 15px;
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 32px);
  }

  .card-3 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  h3 {
    color: red;
  }

  .card-1,
  .card-2,
  .card-3 {
    margin: 30px;
    flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 62px);
    height: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card-1">
      <h3>Reviewer 1</h3>
      <img class="center" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="placeholder">
      <p class="border">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam."</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card-2">
      <h3>Reviewer 2</h3>
      <img class="center " src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="placeholder">
      <p class="border">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam."</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-3">
      <h3>Reviewer 3</h3>
      <img class="center" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="placeholder">
      <p class="border" id="b3">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam."</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunantly (I should have mentioned this at the start my apologies, I'm still getting used to this whole stack overflow thing) at the 600px breakpoint I DO WANT the 3rd 'Reviewer' to be on its own line.

Comment: Updated @AnnaGibson

Comment: i took the left 30% out since it didn't seem to be needed. THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: So now I'm having the OPPOSITE problem. This is what I need: Anything under 600px is columned and centered in the .cards div. Anything above 600px and below 800px has Reviewer 1 and 2 at the top and 3 at the bottom on it's own line. 800px and above has all the reviews  on the same line. Sorry about that

Comment: @AnnaGibson Updated :)